# Operations on file with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, file, io

I'm trying to work with multiThreading and I want to write a code that must do some operations on a specific file called data.txt.

There must be three writers and three readers,writer 1 has to write a random char from A to Z,writer 2 has to write a random number from 1 to 100,writer 3 has to write a random char from this set of characters {*%$#@!&}.

Then readers must read a character from the file data.txt and then reader 1 write this character in file 1.txt,reader 2 write this character in file 2.txt and reader 3 write this character in file 3.txt.

If there was no character in data file to read the readers must wait until the writers add something to the data file.

I have wrote two classes called WriterInFile and ReaderFromFile that extends Thread class but it seems that the ReaderFromFile doesn't work correctly(It doesn't read any characters from data file and doesn't add anything to files 1.txt,2.txt,3.txt)

This is the code for ReaderFromFile class:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReaderFromFile extends Thread {
    private static FileReader reader;
    private int numberOfReader;


    ReaderFromFile(int numberOfReader, FileReader reader) {
        this.numberOfReader = numberOfReader;
        ReaderFromFile.reader = reader;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String s = null;
            try {
                s = readFrom();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FileWriter writer;
        switch (numberOfReader) {
            case 1:
                try {
                    writer = new FileWriter("1.txt",true);
                    if (s != null) {
                        writer.write(s);
                    }
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                try {
                    writer = new FileWriter("2.txt",true);
                    if (s != null) {
                        writer.write(s);
                    }
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                try {
                    writer = new FileWriter("3.txt",true);
                    if (s != null) {
                        writer.write(s);
                    }
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @return the character that has been reed
 */
private synchronized String readFrom() throws IOException {
    String s = null;
    while (!reader.ready()) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        s = String.valueOf(reader.read());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    notifyAll();
    return s;
}


}
```

this is the WriterInFile class:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

public class WriterInFile extends Thread {
private static FileWriter writer;
private int numberOfReader;

WriterInFile(int numberOfReader, FileWriter writer) {
    this.numberOfReader = numberOfReader;
    WriterInFile.writer = writer;
}

public void run() {
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        try {
            sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        switch (numberOfReader) {
            case 1:
                writeChar();
                break;
            case 2:
                writeNumber();
                break;
            case 3:
                writeShape();
                break;
        }
    }
}


private synchronized void writeChar() {
    String s = getRandomChar();
    try {
        writer.write(s);
        System.out.println(s);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    notifyAll();
}

private synchronized void writeNumber() {
    String s = getRandomNumber();
    try {
        writer.write(s);
        System.out.println(s);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    notifyAll();
}

private synchronized void writeShape() {
    String s = getRandomShape();
    try {
        writer.write(s);
        System.out.println(s);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    notifyAll();
}

private String getRandomChar() {
    double randomDouble = Math.random();
    randomDouble = randomDouble * 26;
    int randomInt = (int) randomDouble;
    return String.valueOf((char)(randomInt+'A'));
}

private String getRandomNumber() {
    double randomDouble = Math.random();
    randomDouble = randomDouble * 100 + 1;
    int randomInt = (int) randomDouble;
    return String.valueOf(randomInt);
}


private String getRandomShape() {
    String chars = "*%$#@!&";
    Random rnd = new Random();
    char randomChar = chars.charAt(rnd.nextInt(chars.length()));
    return String.valueOf(randomChar);
}
}
```

and this is the main file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("data.txt");
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("data.txt");
            //creating writers
            WriterInFile writer1 = new WriterInFile(1, writer);
            WriterInFile writer2 = new WriterInFile(2, writer);
            WriterInFile writer3 = new WriterInFile(3, writer);
            // creating readers
            ReaderFromFile reader1 = new ReaderFromFile(1, reader);
            ReaderFromFile reader2 = new ReaderFromFile(2, reader);
            ReaderFromFile reader3 = new ReaderFromFile(3, reader);

            writer1.start();
            writer2.start();
            writer3.start();

            reader1.start();
            reader2.start();
            reader3.start();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: "doen't work correctly"?  Please be more specific.

Comment: You cannot synchronize two or more file objects that are poinining to the same file. You could create a file object in your main, pass that to your readers/writers and in there do synchronized(passedFileObject). Then your code should work. Also take a look of flushing data in your writers within the synchronized block and do not use buffers on your reader side: data could have been inserted within your buffer range

Comment: @ItFreak Isn't it enough to pass just the FileWriter and FileRader object to constructor of Threads?

Comment: @SteveSmith I edited my statement,Thanks

Comment: The main problem is that the readFrom method always return null but I don't know why!